# Path integrals for stochastic equations

Tags: pr.probability, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-equations, stochastic-processes, physics

Does there exist a rigorous mathematical proof for path integral representations given in the physics literature? See for example 
http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9912209v1

For imaginary time rigorous mathematical proof for path integral representations given
in classical paper by Edward Nelson

"Feynman Integrals and the Schrödinger Equation"
Edward Nelson
Citation: J. Math. Phys. 5, 332 (1964); doi: 10.1063/1.1704124
View online: http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.1704124

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Euclidean path integral which can be based on the Wiener measure, there is no mathematically rigorous foundation for the Feynman path integral. For various attempts in this direction see  http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Path_integral:_mathematical_aspects
and http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/path+integral

Comment: Yes. But I have asked about Feynman path integral, given withot any reference to a Wiener measure.